# Is there any similar way in vim to get standard path like neovim stdpath function

Tags: neovim, gvim

In neovim, we can get default standard path via stdpath() function. I wonder if there is any way to do that in vim.

below is the [help doc about `stdpath()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/builtin.html) in neovim:

```
stdpath({what})                 *stdpath()* *E6100*
        Returns |standard-path| locations of various default files and
        directories.

        {what}       Type    Description 
        cache        String  Cache directory. Arbitrary temporary
                             storage for plugins, etc.
        config       String  User configuration directory. The
                             |init.vim| is stored here.
        config_dirs  List    Additional configuration directories.
        data         String  User data directory. The |shada-file|
                             is stored here.
        data_dirs    List    Additional data directories.

        Example:
            :echo stdpath("config")
```

Comment: I don't think there are equivalents for most of those directories in Vim. The closest might be [`$VIM`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html?#%24VIM) for ``stdpath(config)``.

Comment: @muru The equivalent of "config" is actually `~/.vim` on Linux/Unix/MacOS or `$HOME/vimfiles` on Windows. It's the *user* configuration directory...

Comment: @filbranden ah, yes. When the docs said 'The environment variable "$VIM" is used to locate various user files for Vim, such as the user startup script ".vimrc".' I assumed it was actually talking about `~/.vimrc`. But turns out that's only for [Windows and Amiga](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html?#startup) (?!).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.